# Exclude product from been in promotion

Tags: magento2, promotions

We have a promotion that when your cart order value is €50 you can buy a product that is normally €155 for €25.

The issue is, when you add a product for €30 and then add the product that the promotion is then your cart value is €55.

How can we exclude the product that is normally €155 from the cart value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should have used cart rules
Following are the cart attributes on which condition could be applied : Subtotal
Total Items QTY
Total weight

from a product perspective so what you want to achieve will need some additional module/customization to be done to achieve this objective.

Other recommedation is set the cart order value to 75.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks so much for your response. 

We have this module installed: https://www.mexbs.com/additional-promotions-magento2-extension

The issue with raising cart value to 75 is then it is misleading to the customers.